# Can't load CPP14 as lexer or parser

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to execute this

`java -cp .\antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig CPP14 translationUnit -gui example.cc`

command but it showing this error

> Can't load CPP14 as lexer or parser

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure that:

- the classes `CPP14Lexer.java` and `CPP14Parser.java` are generated
- the generated `CPP14Lexer.java` and `CPP14Parser.java` are compiled
- the compiled `CPP14Lexer` and `CPP14Parser` classes are added to the classpath

So, assuming `CPP14Lexer` and `CPP14Parser` are in the default package (and reside in the same folder as the `antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar` file), then your command should look like this:

```
java -cp .\antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar;. org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig CPP14 translationUnit -gui example.cc
```

Comment: Thank you Bart Kiers, It's working perfectly. I got the desired output.

Comment: Good to hear that @RIDOYZZAMAN